Unable to inspect network traffic in expo
I'm developing a react-native app, using expo (v50.0.15).
When developing, I cannot see the network requests I make.
I run on the IOS simulator, using this command; expo run:ios -d
When the app is running, i press j to open the DevTool. I then navigate to the network tap, and interact with my app, so I know a network request has been made. But the network tap remains empty.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
